# How to add listener in firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

i've add on load event like

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);
```

i want to know the the code the
   following two events:

- Before any pictures/flash/js are download
- When the page stops loading     due
  to any reason (may be the user
  stopped it or any anyther reason)

Thank you for the help...

Answer (score 1):

Use the DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: so we have to use it like window.addEventListener("DOMFrameContentLoaded", myeventhandler, *true*); . I'd like to know what is the work of "True"

Comment: @Nok: It defines int which phase the event handler is executed. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html